# How to use an arbitrary amount of usable text boxes from a user inputted number in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, textbox, concatenation

I am writing a program in Python that is a scoring system for a dice game.  The game can have any amount of players so I have an input that allows the user to say how many players they have.

I have been able to print Header Labels into the GUI with each players name.  However my attempt to print a text box for each person so that their round score can be input is giving me trouble.  I tried running a for loop up to the number of players and printing a text box for each person.  The problem with that method, is that it is reusing my    `self.PlayerXroundScore` so only the last text box created is usable.

Here is my code, I have tried to comment as best as possible to make it easier to read.

```
#Allows user to input total number of players
NumPlayers = input("How many players? ")

#Creates a list that is the number of players long
NameList = [0]*NumPlayers

#Allows for input of each Players name
#and stores those names in the list NameList
for i in range(0,NumPlayers):

x = raw_input("Player %d Name? " %(i+1))

NameList[i] = x

#creates the GUI
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *

class App(Tk):
   def __init__(self):
       Tk.__init__(self)

       self.Title = ("10,000 scorekeeping")
       self.Header = Label(self, text = "Welcome to 10,000 scoring Module, Have Fun!!", font = ("helvetica", "20", "bold")).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = (NumPlayers * 3))
       for NameCount in range(1,(NumPlayers+1)):

           #Allows me to create the names as column headers
           self.PlayerName = Label(self, text = "%s" %NameList[NameCount - 1],font = ("helvetica","12","bold")).grid(row = 1, column = ((2 * NameCount)))


           #This if just makes things more aesthetically pleasing, not relevant to my question
           if NameCount < (NumPlayers):

                 self.PlayerName = Label(self, text = "|",font = ("helvetica","12","bold")).grid(row = 1, column = ((2 * NameCount + 1)))


           #This is my problem
           #It succesffully prints the correct number of text boxes
           #however upon button click which calls the vals in each text box
           #only the last created box is useful
           #because that is the box corresponding to PlayerXroundScore
           self.PlayerXroundScore = Entry(self, width = 4)
           self.PlayerXroundScore.grid(row = 2, column = (2 * NameCount))
           self.PlayerXroundScore.insert(0, "0000")

       self.NextRound = Button(self, text = "Next round", command = self.CalcRoundTotals)
       self.NextRound.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

   #This is not completed yet, because I wanted to make sure this is the best way to do it before putting in the time
   #Its obviously doing erroneous things but that will change, 
   #I will encounter the same problem in quite a few different places 
   #but if it can be figured out this once, I can incorporate it elsewhere    
   def CalcRoundTotals(self):

       print x

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    a = App()
    a.mainloop()
```

It really has me vexed.  I thought about concatenating, however, when doing `self.ConcatenatedVarName = Entry(...)` I don't quite know how to do that.  Because, when I concatenate, i do `eval("Player" + CounterInForLoop + "roundScore")`  but SPE doesn't like it when I do that.

Any help at all would be great. I would really like to not write 50(?) if statements that print different amounts of text boxes `if i == NumPlayers`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out on my own, here is the solution for anyone else with a similar problem.

```
self.PlayerTextBox = []
for NameCount in range(1,(NumPlayers + 1)):
      self.PlayerTextBox.append(Entry(self, width = 4))
      self.PlayerTextBox[NameCount - 1].grid(row = 2, column =   
                                       (2 * NameCount))
      self.PlayerTextBox[NameCount - 1].insert(0, "   0")
```

Have some other things to figure out as far as how to print things, but those are minor and I will be able to fix them once I try to.

Thank you to anyone who looked at it and tried to figure it out even if you were unsuccessful.